# A box that allows a friend search on a page - is there a facebook app for this?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, friend, facebook-page

I've seen some similar q and a items on here, but not quite what I'm looking for.

I have a facebook page, and what I would like is to present the user with a search box that allows them to search the friends for that page.  Much like the search box in facebook, if I typed in 'Ale' it would auto-complete with the 'Alexs' etc that are friends with the page.

Note I just want to use a list of friends for the page, and I am admin for that page.  What I would like to do is be able to save the name selected when the user hits submit.

All thoughts gratefully received!

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0):

For pages there is a link under the Like count which will show the list of people who have liked the page in a lightbox window.  I don't believe this is searchable though.

You could make one and put it in your landing page though. Only trouble with this is that for users who already Like the page, they won't get the landing page by default.

Edit: what's it actually for?